# Duplicate Table Filtering to other Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have `table1` and `table2`. If I filter `column1` in `table1` say by AtoZ, is it possible to automatically do the same thing for `table2`. So `column1` in `table2` will now have the same filter as `column1` in `table1`.

Comment: I would consider myself an Excel pro and I've never seen anything like this. You would need to write an Excel Macro (not recommended) or find another way of achieving what you're trying to do.

Comment: The issue is I am using an array forumla and when `Table1` is filtered differently then `Table2`. I get the wrong results. My array formula looks something like this `{=SUM((Table1[Col1]="FreeMember") * (Table2[Col1]=1))}`. Not sure I could rewrite that.